# How to adjust the font of an URL in an R shiny app?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, tags

I have used the following code to create an URL in my shiny App to open google on clicking the link

```
output$Reverse<- renderUI({
   tags$a(href="www.google.com", "Search") })
```

How do I change the font size and color of the word search in the App.

I request someone to help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a style argument to the a-tag using css:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("Reverse")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Reverse<- renderUI({
    tags$a(href="http://www.google.com", "Search", style = "font-size: 200px; color: red;")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```